# Python, Pygame - Rect not working in list

Tags: python

I have a list of rects, just by saying `a = []` then doing `a.append(pygame.Rect(1,1,32,32))`. I can draw this easily by just doing

```
for blocks in a: 
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, blocks)
```

But when I do

```
for blocks in a:
    if  blocks.colliderpoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        #code
```

An error occurs, saying it must be an Rect like style. I don't understand

Comment: Please format your code so it is more easily readable

Comment: And could you try debugging it with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` first and then providing us with all of the information you found if you could not solve it yourself.

Comment: Extra `r` maybe, it's `collidepoint` https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if  blocks.colliderpoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
```

maybe because of the typo?
Change `.colliderpoint` into `.collidepoint` and try again. That should do.

Comment: That did it. Thank you